# How do I Stop IOS opening an embedded google map on a webpage in the IOS maps app?

Tags: google-maps, ios4, ipad-2

I have a webpage with an embedded google map in an iframe. When I visit this page on an iPad2 IOS 4.3.2 (work iPad so its not upgraded to IOS 5) instead of opening the page it launches the IOS google map app. This shows the correct map but not the rest of the webpage content. I want to stop this happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[iPhone HTML link to maps.google.com that opens page in Mobile Safari, not Maps App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154706/iphone-html-link-to-maps-google-com-that-opens-page-in-mobile-safari-not-maps-a)

I stumbled upon this and was able to use the first answer to solve for ipad2. (IOS5). i realize it is not what was asked but it may still help and it was useful.

to reiterate:

VB.net:

```
Dim GMaps as string = "maps.google.com"
Dim addressList as System.Net.IPAdress() = System.Net.DNS.GetHostAddresses(GMaps)

aURL = "http://" & addressList(0).ToString & "/maps?q.......
```